# Set Woocommerce default mail language

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to keep Woocommerce email language on desired language?
E.g Admin language is English and Frontend is French
If you fire a manual email action in admin , it will send mail in English , I want to send it in current frontend language (French)

Comment: you can use a plugin like polylang to have multiple languages https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Comment: No , My means if your admin language is in English , and frontend is French , If you try to send a manual order email from admin , the email is in English , and not in French , I want emails send in Frontend Languages

Comment: In other description , I want to set email temppates send in a Fixed language , regardless to where email is firing . Something lile set local for templates